# INSERT request with variable php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to execute this request but always I get problems when I change string with variable.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO iotdata.cardinfo (Latitude) VALUES ('".$latsave."')" where id = .$id;   

$sql = "INSERT INTO iotdata.cardinfo (Latitude) VALUES ('".$latsave."')" where id = .$id;
```

after "where" they consider it like string not a reserved word.

Comment: You want to execute an error ? It's only normal you get problems I guess

Comment: On a more serious note, your line has a syntax error. The second `"` should be put at the end of the line, not just after `)`

Comment: @ Protectator I want to execute a request not error sorry for this mistake, I tried to put `"` at the end of line but I have the same problem the `where` doesn't look like an sql reserved word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this sir

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO iotdata.cardinfo (Latitude) VALUES ('".$latsave."') where id = '".$id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO iotdata.cardinfo (Latitude) VALUES ('".$latsave."') where id = ".$id;
```

Comment: thank you for your response but I get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace

> $sql = "INSERT INTO iotdata.cardinfo (Latitude) VALUES ('".$latsave."')" where id = .$id;

To

> $sql = "INSERT INTO iotdata.cardinfo (Latitude) VALUES ('".$latsave."') where id =" .$id;

Comment: thank you for your response, but I get the same problem the `where` look like a string not a reserved word (such as INSERT & INTO)